# Electrum won't send bitcoin: ascii error

Tags: wallet, client, electrum

I was trying to transfer some bitcoins from my electrum wallet to coinbase. However Electrum I get this ascii error whenever I attempt a transfer:

"ascii codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

I have no idea on what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Are you copy-pasting an address into electrum that has non-ascii characters? If so, try retyping the address.

Comment: The characters in the address are all ascii characters. I tried retyping the address multiple times but same error

Comment: the error occurs after I type my password. Even when I try to sign the transaction

Comment: Is there a non-ASCII character in your password?

Comment: And can you edit your question to make it clear *exactly* when this message appears (i.e. what exact sequence of clicks / keystrokes you did)?

Comment: I have similar issue, "ascii codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)" After password changed as well. I think it is a Python problem with unicode or something like that but how can I fix it? THanks.

Comment: I have a similar error: ascii codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, it was reported and fixed yesterday: 
https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/1967

I will make a new release later today, that will include that fix.